# How to use completion block using SDWebImage in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, sdwebimage

Am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download image. I want to do further operation if image is downloaded successfully.

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "App-Default"), completed: {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: URL!) -> Void in
      // Perform operation. 
})
```

But I am getting error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(UIImage!, NSError!, SDImageCacheType, URL!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SDExternalCompletionBlock?'

Comment: I am getting this error...Cannot convert value of type '(UIImage!, NSError!, SDImageCacheType, URL!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SDExternalCompletionBlock?'

Comment: That should not be a comment, that should be posted with your question

Comment: my code is :   cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "App-Default"), completed: {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: URL!) -> Void in
                
                // Perform operation.
            })

Comment: I am using updated SDWebImage library.

Answer (score 17):

Finally solved.

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
 // Perform operation.
})
```

Comment: Thanks Man! My mistake was passing SDWebImageOptions: nil. This solved it. :)

Answer (score 13):

**SWIFT 4-5 version**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://some_url")
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
     // your rest code
})
```

**Important!**
Don't forget to send self as weak or unowned (like this [self weak]/[self unowned]) to the block, when it is necessary, to avoid retain cycles.

Example:

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(
     with: url,
     placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),
     options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0),
     completed: { [self weak] image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                  guard let selfNotNil = self else { return }
                  // your rest code
        }
)
```

Answer (score 11):

**Updates: SWIFT 5 SDWebImage 5.x.x**

```
        cell.imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Failed to load image
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
            } else {
                // Successful in loading image
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
```

========================================================================

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (img, err, cacheType, imgURL) in
     // code
})
```

Try this, hope this will work fine

Answer (score 3):

According to the `typedef` in the framework you're using:

```
typedef void(^SDExternalCompletionBlock)(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL);
```

an `SDExternalCompletionBlock` consists of optional parameters as indicated by `_Nullable`. Therefor your code should be written like this:

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "App-Default"), completed: {(image: UIImage?, error: NSError?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: URL?) -> Void in
      // Perform operation. 
})
```

Since the compiler knows the types of the completion block's parameters (from the function declaration) you can write the code more succinctly and (IMO) easier to read like this:

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
      // Perform operation. 
})
```

Comment: I have implemented first one..Getting error..Cannot invoke 'sd_setImage' with an argument list of type '(with: URL, placeholderImage: UIImage?, completed: (UIImage?, NSError?, SDImageCacheType, URL?) -> Void)'

Comment: If implement second one..Getting error..Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage'

Comment: Autocomplete gives  cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: URL?, placeholderImage: UIImage?, completed:SDExternalCompletionBlock?)

Comment: Tried last updated code..Getting error..Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage'

Comment: Finally done I used...cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                // Perform operation.
            })

Comment: Thank you jjatie for your time and support.

Comment: ah, I didn't see the API including `options:`. You don't need to (and shouldn't) force unwrap `url`

Answer (score 2):

This one also works with swift 3 :

```
cell.appIcon.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"), options: []) { (image, error, imageCacheType, imageUrl) in
            // Perform your operations here.
}
```