# Issue with getting image from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am loading images in my collection view using `SDWebImage` like so...

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"appLogo.jpg"))
```

Now I want in an array all the images thus obtained from the url & assigned to the `imageView` . So what should be done.

Please note..I don't want the url's in an array but instead the images I get from those url's.

Comment: Use `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:` instead and in the `completed` closure, add the image obtained in your array?

Comment: hmm...ok..could you mind giving the format you suggested to the line of code I put..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956568/1801544 for the code. You have in the closure "image", "append it to your array" (I'd say that a dict with key as "index" may be better solution)?

Comment: ok..let me check..

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Larme..it worked!..Do put it up as an answer andI'll accept it...