# How to add alpha property to an UIImage set with SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, sdwebimage

I am using the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) plugin on Xcode for my images but I need to add an alpha effect (transparency) to it but it won't recognize the property.

I know I can do something like this for a regular UIImage and it would work...

```
posterBackground.image = UIImage(with: URL(string: movieImage!)!.alpha(0.15)
```

But trying the same with the SDWebImage plugin in doesn't works...

```
posterBackground.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: movieImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "poster-placeholder"))!.alpha(0.15)
```

It gives me the error "Value of tuple type 'Void' has no member 'apha'". Is there some way that allows me to use the plugin and apply the alpha property to the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your completion block should have returned an image, can't you manipulate things from the block?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, using the completion block that SDWebImage provides did the trick!

Comment: glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Happiehappie 's comment and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40629552/8862620) from another post I was able to apply the alpha property. Here is the final working code...

```
posterBackground.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: movieImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "poster-placeholder"), options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in   
    self.posterBackground.image = image?.alpha(0.15)
})
```